# How to initialize Osmand project for Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, osmand

Is there any tutorial of how to initialize Osmand for Android Studio?
Every time I try to build the project, I receive errors because of missing resources:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :OsmAndCore-sample:generateArmv5DebugSources, :OsmAndCore-sample:generateArmv5DebugAndroidTestSources, :OsmAndCore-sample:prepareArmv5DebugUnitTestDependencies, :OsmAndCore-sample:mockableAndroidJar, :OsmAnd:generateFreeLegacyArmv5DebugSources, :OsmAnd:mockableAndroidJar, :OsmAnd:prepareFreeLegacyArmv5DebugUnitTestDependencies, :OsmAnd:generateFreeLegacyArmv5DebugAndroidTestSources, :plugins:Osmand-SRTMPlugin:generateDebugSources, :plugins:Osmand-SRTMPlugin:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :plugins:Osmand-SRTMPlugin:mockableAndroidJar, :plugins:Osmand-SRTMPlugin:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :plugins:Osmand-ParkingPlugin:generateDebugSources, :plugins:Osmand-ParkingPlugin:mockableAndroidJar, :plugins:Osmand-ParkingPlugin:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :plugins:Osmand-ParkingPlugin:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
Validating translations
:OsmAnd:clean
:OsmAnd-java:clean
:OsmAndCore-sample:clean
:plugins:Osmand-ParkingPlugin:clean UP-TO-DATE
:plugins:Osmand-SRTMPlugin:clean UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAndCore-sample:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAndCore-sample:preArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAndCore-sample:checkArmv5DebugManifest
:OsmAnd-java:compileJava
Warning:[options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
/home/thomas/osmandapp/android/OsmAnd-java/src/com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser.java
Warning:(113, 7) unreachable catch clause
thrown type InvalidProtocolBufferException has already been caught
Warning:(150, 7) unreachable catch clause
thrown type InvalidProtocolBufferException has already been caught
Note: /home/thomas/osmandapp/android/OsmAnd-java/src/net/osmand/util/GeoPointParserUtil.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 warnings
:OsmAnd-java:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd-java:classes
:OsmAnd-java:androidJar
:OsmAndCore-sample:preArmv5NativeDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAndCore-sample:preArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAndCore-sample:preArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAndCore-sample:preArmv7NativeDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAndCore-sample:preArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAndCore-sample:preFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAndCore-sample:preFatNativeDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAndCore-sample:preFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAndCore-sample:preMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAndCore-sample:preMipsNativeDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAndCore-sample:preMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAndCore-sample:preX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAndCore-sample:preX86NativeDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAndCore-sample:preX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAndCore-sample:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2330Library
:OsmAndCore-sample:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72330Library
:OsmAndCore-sample:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42330Library
:OsmAndCore-sample:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2330Library
:OsmAndCore-sample:prepareNetOsmandOsmAndCore_android01SNAPSHOTLibrary
:OsmAndCore-sample:prepareNetOsmandOsmAndCore_androidNativeRelease01SNAPSHOTLibrary
:OsmAndCore-sample:prepareArmv5DebugDependencies
:OsmAndCore-sample:compileArmv5DebugAidl
:OsmAndCore-sample:compileArmv5DebugRenderscript
:OsmAndCore-sample:generateArmv5DebugBuildConfig
:OsmAndCore-sample:mergeArmv5DebugShaders
:OsmAndCore-sample:compileArmv5DebugShaders
:OsmAndCore-sample:generateArmv5DebugAssets
:OsmAndCore-sample:mergeArmv5DebugAssets
:OsmAndCore-sample:generateArmv5DebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAndCore-sample:generateArmv5DebugResources
:OsmAndCore-sample:mergeArmv5DebugResources
:OsmAndCore-sample:processArmv5DebugManifest
:OsmAndCore-sample:processArmv5DebugResources
:OsmAndCore-sample:generateArmv5DebugSources
:OsmAndCore-sample:preArmv5DebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAndCore-sample:prepareArmv5DebugAndroidTestDependencies
:OsmAndCore-sample:compileArmv5DebugAndroidTestAidl
:OsmAndCore-sample:processArmv5DebugAndroidTestManifest
:OsmAndCore-sample:compileArmv5DebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:OsmAndCore-sample:generateArmv5DebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:OsmAndCore-sample:mergeArmv5DebugAndroidTestShaders
:OsmAndCore-sample:compileArmv5DebugAndroidTestShaders
:OsmAndCore-sample:generateArmv5DebugAndroidTestAssets
:OsmAndCore-sample:mergeArmv5DebugAndroidTestAssets
:OsmAndCore-sample:generateArmv5DebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAndCore-sample:generateArmv5DebugAndroidTestResources
:OsmAndCore-sample:mergeArmv5DebugAndroidTestResources
:OsmAndCore-sample:processArmv5DebugAndroidTestResources
:OsmAndCore-sample:generateArmv5DebugAndroidTestSources
:OsmAndCore-sample:preArmv5DebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAndCore-sample:prepareArmv5DebugUnitTestDependencies
:OsmAndCore-sample:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:checkFreeLegacyArmv5DebugManifest
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevLegacyArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevLegacyArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevLegacyArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevLegacyArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevLegacyFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevLegacyFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevLegacyMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevLegacyMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevLegacyX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevLegacyX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoreArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoreArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoreArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoreArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoreFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoreFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoreMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoreMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoreX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoreX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoredebugArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoredebugArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoredebugArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoredebugArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoredebugFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoredebugFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoredebugMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoredebugMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoredebugX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoredebugX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2330Library
:OsmAnd:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72330Library
:OsmAnd:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72330Library
:OsmAnd:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2330Library
:OsmAnd:prepareComAndroidSupportGridlayoutV72330Library
:OsmAnd:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library
:OsmAnd:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72330Library
:OsmAnd:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42330Library
:OsmAnd:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2330Library
:OsmAnd:prepareFreeLegacyArmv5DebugDependencies
:OsmAnd:compileFreeLegacyArmv5DebugAidl
:OsmAnd:compileFreeLegacyArmv5DebugRenderscript
:OsmAnd:generateFreeLegacyArmv5DebugBuildConfig
:OsmAnd:mergeFreeLegacyArmv5DebugShaders
:OsmAnd:compileFreeLegacyArmv5DebugShaders
:OsmAnd:generateFreeLegacyArmv5DebugAssets
:OsmAnd:mergeFreeLegacyArmv5DebugAssets
:OsmAnd:generateFreeLegacyArmv5DebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:generateFreeLegacyArmv5DebugResources
:OsmAnd:mergeFreeLegacyArmv5DebugResources
:OsmAnd:processFreeLegacyArmv5DebugManifest
:OsmAnd:processFreeLegacyArmv5DebugResources
/home/thomas/osmandapp/android/OsmAnd/res/layout/dash_osmo_fragment.xml
Error:(22, 27) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/osmo').
/home/thomas/osmandapp/android/OsmAnd/res/layout/fragment_edit_poi_advanced.xml
Error:(40, 39) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/tag_poi_name').
Error:(81, 39) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/tag_poi_amenity').
/home/thomas/osmandapp/android/OsmAnd/res/layout/poi_tag_list_item.xml
Error:(22, 27) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'hint' with value '@string/hint_tag').
Error:(36, 27) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'hint' with value '@string/hint_value').
/home/thomas/osmandapp/android/OsmAnd/res/layout/subscription_fragment.xml
Error:(240, 43) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/osm_live_default_price').
Error:Execution failed for task ':OsmAnd:processFreeLegacyArmv5DebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/thomas/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.3/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 37.241 secs
Information:7 errors
Information:3 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

I know that I need to download an additional "resources" repository, which I did like mentioned in this post:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/osmand/wikis/GradleCommandLineBuildEnvironment.wiki

But I don't know how to include these resources to my Android Studio project.